# Ubuntu 18.04 How to remove the "Tip:...Livepatch..." message

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Whenever I update manually under the final notice: "The software on this computer is up to date"
I see the message: "Tip: You can use Livepatch to keep your computer more secure..."

I do not use snap and **do not** want to install Livepatch.

How can I remove the "Tip:.." message?

It's aesthetically displeasing.

Comment: What OS version? What are you using to do the update (apt-get? update-manager?). I've never seen this message other than with an ssh login -- possibly coming from /etc/update-motd.d/80-livepatch (motd = Message of the Day).

Comment: See header: Ubuntu 18.04.   Using (from drop-down menu) Applications -> System tools -> Administration -> SoftwareUpdater

Answer (score 6):

copy /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Dialogs.py to
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Dialogs.py-backup

Edit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Dialogs.py

Look for a string containing "Tip:" and replace the entire string with spaces

Seems to have worked for me, in 18.04. No guarantees!

update jan, 2021: still works on Ub. 20.04

Changes will probably disappear if/when update-manager is updated.

Comment: I just deleted that whole line of code, and it worked for me

Comment: I've changed the function `_is_livepatch_supported` to always return `False`